# How can I register a Visual Basic 6.0 DLL file in the GAC to be able to add it as a reference in a SSIS script task

Tags: .net, dll, gac

How can I register a Visual Basic 6.0 DLL file in the [global assembly cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) (GAC) to be able to add it as a reference in a SQL Server integration services script task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only .NET assemblies can be registered in the GAC. A Visual Basic 6.0 DLL file is just not qualified. You can build a .NET assembly that exposes the Visual Basic 6.0 DLL file (COM) types and methods to managed code, and register that in the GAC.